# Use two different ways to calculate OR exlusive permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am asked to solve the following question:

> A license plate that is composed of exactly 3 letters and 3 identical. Order matters. So how many arrangements are there that satisfies: 3 letters are identical OR 3 digits are identical

Once I get this question, I thought of the inclusion-exclusion formula. So I calculate first cases where 3 letters are identical plus cases where 3 digits are identical minus cases where both 3 letters and 3 digits are identical:

$$\text{Case where 3 letters are identical}: 10^3*26*C(6,3) = 520000$$
$$\text{Case where 3 digits are identical}: 10*26^3*C(6,3) = 3515200 $$

$$\text{Case where both digits and letters are identical}: 10*26*C(6,3) = 5200 $$

$$\textbf{In total we have}: 520000+3515200-5200 = 4030000 $$

In order to verify my answer, I decide to use another way to calculate this by using a universal set minus the set where all letters and digits are not identical:

$$\text{Without restrictions}: 10^3*26^3*C(6,3) = 351520000$$
$$\text{Case where none of the digits or letters are identical}: 10*9*8*26*25*24*C(6,3) = 224640000 $$

$$\textbf{In total we have}: 351520000-224640000 = 12688000 $$

So the results are not equal. However, I have been using these two methods to verify my answers many times already. It has always worked. So I am not sure where I did wrong.

I even tried to try a smaller problem (where I use only two letters and two numbers so I can actually count one by one), and in that situation, both ways of solving this problem gave me the same result, as it should have.

I am totally lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subtraction, you missed the cases where two of the digits are identical or where two of the letters are identical.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I totally forgot that situation. I was stuck on this question for almost one hour :( Thanks for reminding me this

Comment: So it seems like this question will be very complicated in my second way of doing this. Since I will have to consider more cases

Comment: I am not sure I would call it very complicated, but it is more work than the first method.

Comment: Sure then I would go for the first method. Thank you for saving me from keeping stuck on this question haha